# Convert string expression to date type in PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I have below code in PS:

```
Connect-AzureAD 
$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent 
Get-AzureADUser -All:$true |Select ObjectId,UserPrincipalName,@{Name='ExpirationDate'; Expression={(Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).Get_Item("createdDateTime")}} 
| Export-CSV "$PSScriptRoot\userslist.csv"
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

I want to convert string *createdDateTime* to a dateTime format, so I can add +60 days to it (*.AddDays(60))*. I tried without conversion but it didn't work.

```
Expression={(...).Get_Item("createdDateTime")}}
```

I tried also with function *[datetime]::ParseExact* but I did something wrong (no error in the console), because the column in output was blank.

Please advise

EDIT
This is what I get after I run the whole script Pamela gave. No error in the console. Any ideas why is so?

[image]

Comment: Can you post an example value of `createdDateTime`, so we know what values need to be parsed?

Comment: I got sth like this `CreationDate      : 19.10.2020 13:55:29` in the output

Comment: I'm not convinced the `createdDateTime` is a string at all. This is just how it is stringified for display. Can you do a `Get_Item("createdDateTime").GetType()` please to confirm it is not already a DateTime object?

Comment: @Theo I did it. It shows System.String type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried with your code and get the time, it looks like "2/16/2021 5:55:03 AM":

[image]

So I format the string with `'M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt'`.

```
$string = "2/16/2021 5:55:03 AM"
[Datetime]::ParseExact($string, 'M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt', $null)
```

[image]

As you said in the comment, your CreationDate is like "19.10.2020 13:55:29", so `d.M.yyyy H:mm:ss` should work(not sure M or MM in yours, you could check more CreationDate).

Format the datetime and add 60 days:

```
Get-AzureADUser -All:$true |Select ObjectId,UserPrincipalName,@{Name='ExpirationDate'; Expression={[Datetime]::ParseExact((Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).Get_Item("createdDateTime"), 'd.M.yyyy H:mm:ss', $null).AddDays(60)}}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it for one string but I want to use this for whole output (column) -  include function `[Datetime]::ParseExact` into `Expression={(...).Get_Item("createdDateTime")}}` and add +60 days. Can this be done?

Comment: @Jaxer Of course you could, try like this `Get-AzureADUser -All:$true |Select ObjectId,UserPrincipalName,@{Name='ExpirationDate'; Expression={[Datetime]::ParseExact((Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.ObjectId).Get_Item("createdDateTime"), 'M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt', $null).AddDays(60)}}`.

Comment: And here is the problem I mentioned in the post. If I do like this I got the column `ExpiratonDate` blank :/. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: This is because the format is not suitable for yours. As you said in the comment, your CreationDate is like "19.10.2020 13:55:29", so `M.d.yyyy H:mm:ss` should work(not sure M or MM in yours, you could check more CreationDate). I have edited my answer to share the screenshots, the last one which adding days is tested on another computer so the format is different.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. But I guess it may be caused by the format that I mentioned "`MM` or `M`". For example, if the create times are `19.10.2020 13:55:29` and `9.8.2020 5:55:29`, the format will be `d.M.yyyy H:mm:ss`. If the day, month, and hour all have two digits, it will be `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss`. I‘m sorry:(  `M.d.yyyy H:mm:ss` is incorrect in the comment, I typed wrong, hope this can finally help.

Comment: Yes, this was the case. I have just figured it out and deleted the comment. It should be `d.M.yyyy H:mm:ss`. Problem solved. Thank you :)